# Error Unable to access the selected application, Unresolved application library references

Tags: docker, weblogic, weblogic12c

while trying to deploy an ADF project in Weblogic 12.2.1 docker container ,I get the following errors:

```
Error Unable to access the selected application.
Error org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.ResourceServlet
Error org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.ResourceServlet
Error org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.ResourceServlet
```

[this is what i get when i deploy the project][1]

```
<Dec 14, 2017 7:01:58 AM GMT> <Warning> <J2EE> <BEA-160188> <Unresolved application library references, for application TrendzV3App-3.10.4-2.ear, defined in weblogic-application.xml: [Extension-Name: adf.oracle.domain, exact-match: false], [Extension-Name: trendzV3Images, exact-match: false], [Extension-Name: oracle.jsp.next, exact-match: false].> 
<Dec 14, 2017 7:01:58 AM GMT> <Warning> <J2EE> <BEA-160188> <Unresolved WebApp library references defined in weblogic.xml, of module 'TrendzAppwebapp.war' [Extension-Name: adf.oracle.domain.webapp, exact-match: false].> 
<Dec 14, 2017 7:02:00 AM GMT> <Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160228> <AppMerge failed to merge your application. If you are running AppMerge on the command-line, merge again with the -verbose option for more details. See the error message(s) below.> 
weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException:
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.ResourceServlet
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.handleStateChangeException(FlowDriver.java:55)
```

How can I get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this just to make sure that no starters make the same mistake as i did.

This is not an actual solution to my problem but i'm hoping that this will be helpul in determining that solution.

For starters like me, first of all make sure that you have the right docker image of the respective Weblogic version..

I have been trying to deploy an ADF application using the docker image build using Weblogic-quick-installer.

Instead use Oracle-Fusion-Middleware-Infrastructure for more oracle based application support.

Once the weblogic is up and running make sure that all the library files are present in the deployements in your console or you may need to add them.

And also if you get an error like this :

```
Unresolved application library references
```

Make sure that all the libraries that you see in the deployments are targeted(see the target tab of the server) to the Managed-servers that you deployed your application to.